# CSS :first-letter coding won't work

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS.  I'm having problems getting my pseudo elements to work in paragraphs.  The CSS I'm writing is

```
a:first-letter  { 
  font-size:3em;
}
```

The HTML code is

```
<p>Lorem ipsum, etc to end of paragraph</p>
```

The same thing happens with the before/after pseudo elements as we'll.  the browser I'm using is Safari. I'm sure I've typed it out correctly but it just doesn't work.  Any suggestions gratefully received.

Thanks,
Ingrid

Comment: `:first-letter` works only on block-elements. `a` is an inline-element.

Comment: your selector looks for <a> tag not for <p>

Comment: _I'm sure I've typed it out correctly_. No you have not :)

Comment: @gearsdigital the use of :  `inline-block` is just fine.

Comment: @GCyrillus **I** know ;) Just wanted to point out the obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Well you did said *paragraphs* but your CSS rule is applied to an anchor (link) instead of a paragraph.

So you might want to do something like:

```
p:first-letter { font-size:3em; }
```

After I checked, the `:first-letter` pseudo element indeed doesn't work for inline elements and if you wan't to use it on an `<a>` you have to define your element as an `inline-block` or `block` element:

```
a { 
    display: inline-block;
    /* Since inline-block doesn't work on IE 7 and below you will need the following hack */
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mS9Lj/1/) example.

Comment: Sorry, I did type in p:first-letter and it doesn't work.  Previous email is a typo.  Thanks

Comment: Which Browser are you using? `:first-letter` does not work in Internet Explorer 8 and below. The Example listed here does work in modern browsers! http://jsfiddle.net/9y5PY/

Comment: I'm using Safari 7.0.2

Comment: @gearsdigital , sorry :) , but yes it does work there , it even worked in IE6 (little buggy sometimes, but it did :) :first-letter and :first-line are in spec for so long , that it must work every where almost since ever

Comment: Oh yes, you're right! I was confused by `:first-line`.

Comment: @gearsdigital `:first-line` is a CSS2 feature and is compatible with IE 5.5+

Comment: Doesn't seem like there's a solution then?

Comment: @user3478791 On the contrary. It will certainly work in every browser made in the last 13+ years.